# Looking for a good definition of a map, and if maps can be implemented using trees

Tags: data-structures

I'm going through some potential interview questions, one of which being can you implement a map or a linked list using a tree.

But even after some time googling I don't have a clear idea exactly what a map is, how it differs from an array or a hash table for example. Could anybody provide a clear description.

Can it, and a linked list be written as a tree?

Comment: Personally, I find Wikipedia's computer science articles to be pretty damn good, overall. That said, they are *not* (generally) tutorials, and you're better off going elsewhere if you're completely unfamiliar with the concepts they're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can it (a map), and a linked list be written as a tree?

Maps are *usually* represented with arrays.  To determine where an entry goes in a map, you need to compute its *key*.  Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) for a better explanation.

Trees (with an undetermined number of nodes) can be implemented using lists (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)#Tree_representations) for further discussion).  Lists are not usually implemented as trees.

I'd encourage you to get [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844) which is a classic on data structures and will give you alot of really great information.

Answer (score 1):

A Map, aka Dictionary or associative array, is a data structure that allows you to look up a value using a key.

A Java Map can be implemented as a HashMap or a TreeMap; that suggests that hash map is one possible implementation and yes, you can implement a Map as a tree.

Comment: Can't the index into a regular array be regarded as a key? Thus how does a map differ from a plain vanilla array?

Comment: It can be if you restrict yourself to integer keys.  But a Map can use any hashable, immutable Object into a key.

Comment: also, an array becomes inefficient when the keys are widely spaced (it would become sparse).